# Why can't I define both implicit and explicit operators?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Why I cannot define both implicit and explicit operators like so?

```
    public class C
    {
        public static implicit operator string(C c)
        {
            return "implicit";
        }

        public static explicit operator string(C c)
        {
            return "explicit";
        }
    }
```

You can do this hack though :)

```
    class Program
    {
        public class A
        {

        }

        public class B
        {
            public static implicit operator A(B b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("implicit");
                return new A();
            }
        }

        public class C : B
        {
            public static explicit operator A(C c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("explicit");
                return new A();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            C c = new C();

            A a = c;
            A b = (A) c;
        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
implicit
explicit
```

Comment: Who says you can't?  I.e., what happens when you try?

Comment: Why would you want different implementations between the two?

Comment: Overriding ToString is not even CLOSE to an implicit cast operator. Your example code only works because Console.WriteLine has an object overload and calls ToString() on the object.

Comment: It was intended for fun, I even placed smily face there.

Comment: But it doesn't achieve the desired effect. You cannot pass C around as a string without the explicit cast. The receiving code would be dependent on calling ToString for the 'implicit' operator.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it is a JOKE.

Answer (score 61):

Check this: [Why can't coexist implicit and explicit operator of the same type in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892278/why-cant-coexist-implicit-and-explicit-operator-of-the-same-type-in-c)

If you define an explicit operator, you will be able to do something like this:

```
Thing thing = (Thing)"value";
```

If you define an implicit operator, you can still do the above, but you can also take advantage of implicit conversion:

```
Thing thing = "value";
```

In short, explicit allows only explicit conversion, while implicit allows both explicit and implicit... hence the reason why you can only define one.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know the technical limitation that prevents this, but I think they would have done this to prevent people from shooting their own feet off.

```
string imp = new C(); // = "implicit"
string exp = (string)new C(); // = "explicit"
```

That would drive me bonkers and makes no sense, `C` should only cast to a string 1 way, not 2 different ways.

Comment: You can do it two way, you just cannot do a custom conversion for both.

Comment: No you cannot do it, ToString is not a cast operator.